# Python - Using a while loop with an if/elif statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but I have a feeling it has something to do with how I've structured the while loop. I want the loop to continue only if the user inputs something other than the two choices they have. However, even when I test it with putting in either of the two correct choices, the while loop continues.

```
prompt = "> "

print "Welcome to the converter. What would you like \
to convert? (temp or distance)"
choice = raw_input(prompt)

while (choice != "temp" or choice != "distance"):
    print "Sorry, that's not an option"
    choice = raw_input(prompt)
if choice == "temp":
    print "temp"
elif choice == "distance":
    print "distance"
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the `if` statement to be part of the `while` loop, you need to put it at the same indentation level.

Comment: It looks like you're just starting to learn python, you should really learn python 3, it's out for 10 years already, has fewer quirks and more features.

Comment: @SethMMorton that's not what he wants. the while loop is just to keep asking for a new value until a valid one is provided

Comment: If my answer solves your problem please accept it. If it doesn't let me know what is still the problem and I'll try to help you with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want choice to be either "temp" or "distance", so your while condition should be that it can't (not be "temp" AND not be "distance"). Just substitute the `or` for `and` on the `while` condition.

```
prompt = "> "

print "Welcome to the converter. What would you like \
to convert? (temp or distance)"
choice = raw_input(prompt)

while (choice != "temp" and choice != "distance"):
    print "Sorry, that's not an option"
    choice = raw_input(prompt)
if choice == "temp":
    print "temp"
elif choice == "distance":
    print "distance"
```

The way you had it before the condition would always be true

Per suggestions below other ways you could write the while condition that would also work:

```
while not (choice == "temp" or choice == "distance"):
```

or

```
while (choice not in ('temp', 'distance')):
```

Take your pick.

Comment: Psst:  DeMorgan's laws would go a long way to making that conditional more readable.

Comment: And, of course, another option is `choice not in ('temp', 'distance')`

Comment: @dietbacon, thank you! That makes sense - I basically created an infinite loop with the while statement because no matter what choice would either be "not distance" or "not temp". You explained it very well. I changed the "or" to "and" and everything works as expected now.

Comment: @MasterModnar no problem, thats what we're here for :)